# Is this question dealing with a speech impediment on topic?

Tags: discussion

We have this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/321018/127901) that was asked about dealing with a speech impediment that closed and has been since reopened. Should it be open? If so how is it on topic?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Voting to reopen now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This question that was asked about dealing with a speech impediment

Whether or not the stutterer needs to work on his speech outside of gaming mostly *irrelevant* to the topic of communicating specific, relevant **gameplay** information, and it's that gameplay communication expertise I feel we can (and have) provided.

If you want to deconstruct the question to it's base parts, I suggest we boil it down to this quote:

> How we can help him to **convey information to us quickly?**

Yes, this question is about communication. But hey, being able to communicate valid, useful information in a multiplayer gaming setting is actually [pretty](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/2u2jwf/huge_difference_in_communication_between_na_and/) darn [relevant](http://www.pcgamer.com/learning-to-communicate-more-effectively-in-dota-2/) to [a lot](http://on-winning.com/communication-team-based-games/) of [games](https://boards.oce.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/gameplay-strategy/mRxbcJ74-in-game-voice-comms) (and reading between the lines, a lot of gamers). In fact, a lot of multiplayer gaming communities have their own [shorthand callouts/lingo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/what-do-those-abbreviations-mean-in-league-of-legends), nicknames for [characters / team members / weapons / buildings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275025/what-does-rax-mean), loadout/[build order](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4474/what-does-a-timing-push-mean) slang, [areas/features](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/253159/28182) on maps, and so on (there is a lot more under [terminology](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)).

Even if you take the current answer which focuses on CoD: Zombies and the various intricacies of that game mode: The answerer gives both **game-specific expertise** (advice on pre-planning, and various roles players can take, whether to follow vs lead) as well as generalised coop communication advice (keep communication to simple, short phrases and words).

Thus, I believe it's on-topic for us and should remain open, although it should probably be tagged specifically with the Call of Duty game OP & friend is playing.

Comment: And if the question was asking about those game specific items, I don't think this would be *nearly* this contentious.  But your reading of the question is mangling what's actually being asked, which is specific to the speech impediment.  There's literally *nothing* in the question asking for lingo or anything game specific.  Heck, the question was specifically *not* tagged with any singular game, driving the generality home that much more.

Comment: @Frank While the question is worded in a fairly general way, the question asker might not have known to ask about those things in specific. They might have to ask "How do I play Zombies better with my friend?" to then know to ask "What short names/map strategies can I use with my friend?". It might help if they tagged the question with the specific version of CoD that they're talking about, so answers could incorporate advice particular to that game.

Comment: @Broneironaut The way I see it, the question is being asked in the general sense, while using a specific game as an example. You can answer it in the specific, but from a general sense, its not going to be a problem with games; its how to function with a speech impediment. My entire point hinges on the fact that it's *not* asking in the specific, but in the general.

Comment: @Frank I disagree, the solutions that were posted were directly related to games. They gave suggestions for how to minimize the effect of the stutter with *in-game suggestions*. A majority of the top answer would not be valid for a question that wasn't related to gaming.

Comment: @Childishforlife The *answers* are specific. The **question** is not. We're discussing the question, not the answers. And its not at *all* game specific, which is the entire problem.

Comment: I don't see the need to delete the question though, it is a unique and interesting question and while it may be *slightly* off topic, the general intent of the question was about gaming and we should try to help him.

Comment: @Frank I've re-read the question several times over the past few days and I got to say, what ever you are seeing in there, I'm not seeing it. Help us out, will you? I get the impression you almost think we're asked to cure stuttering, or something.

Comment: @DJPirtu I'm in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68421/discussion-on-question-by-danny-beckett-tips-on-using-a-headset-with-a-stutter), if you want to discuss.  But I'd recommend re-reading what's already there, because I'm very tired of repeating myself.

Answer (score 3):

1.) The question is on-topic because it asks about gameplay strategies and tactics.

As in, a strategy the asker can use to approach a gameplay challenge. If you remove the gameplay aspect from the problem then it stops being on-topic, but fortunately there haven't been any edits to remove the gameplay aspect. The question was never about overcoming stuttering in any situation other than gaming and the hypothetical question of whether this would be on-topic "if you remove everything about gaming in the question" shouldn't have any bearing on the question we're looking at.

2.) The problem fits perfectly in the tag used.

The Health tag is defined as: "Questions dealing with real-life health issues related to gaming, such as muscle strain or vision problems." I'm having difficulty thinking of a question using this tag that, "if you remove everything about gaming in the question", could still be on-topic. Looking at the top voted questions on the tag, I see problems based around computer screens, desk ergonomics, mouse control, button input methods, and sound design, but those provided interesting and useful gaming answers and their votes and age show they're clearly on topic and welcome.

3.) This isn't the same question if you remove the gaming concerns.

There are very few real-life examples I can think of where you need to deliver information as quickly, clearly, and succinctly as a multiplayer game. It's a skill, and based off of televised matches of professional gaming competitions it's a very specific skill that has no good comparison to communication outside of games and it's realistically only needed in a gaming environment. It's disingenuous to say that trying to solve this problem in gaming is related to solving it in any other situation unrelated to games.

Comment: 1) It asks nothing of the sort. 2) Existence of tags doesn't automatically mean the question is on-topic. 3) This is very much the exact same issue, both in and out of game.

Comment: @Frank I disagree with your response, especially to point 1 and 3, but I'll let the voters decide this one. You and I clearly have different and equally valid ideas of what constitutes a question relating to games, and I can't offer a more valid response to you than "It does, though."

Answer (score 2):

I feel this question is off topic and should be closed and deleted. It is only tangentially related to gaming because of where they encountered the problem, however you could remove everything about gaming in the question and it wouldn't change the core of the question at all. Thus it is not a gaming question, but a communication problem and not on topic for Arqade.

Comment: At the end of the day, a speech problem isn't a gaming problem unless it happens only *in* a game, due to a technical glitch or other software problem.  When the problem persists out of a game, just like tech support, it is outside what we can consider to be a gaming problem.

Comment: Which begs the question why we even have the health tag: "Questions dealing with real-life health issues related to gaming, such as muscle strain or vision problems." I'm having difficulty thinking of a question that would be on-topic using your interpretation.